# primevue datatable toggle Column with filters template any Solution?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, primevue

I am trying to add filters to a DataTable using filters feature from PrimeVue.
**in the documentation**

```
  <DataTable value={products} header={header}
 responsiveLayout="scroll"><Column field="code" header="Code" />{columnComponents}</DataTable>
```

> primevue datatable toggle Column with filters template any Solution ?

```
    and here what i have 
      <DataTable
            ref="dt"
            :value="calls"
            :paginator="true"
            class="p-datatable-calls"
            :rows="10"
            dataKey="id"
            :rowHover="true"
            v-model:selection="selectedcalls"
            v-model:filters="filters"
            filterDisplay="menu"
            :loading="loading"
            paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
            :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 25, 50]"
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
            :globalFilterFields="['call', 'destination', 'area', 'status']"
            responsiveLayout="scroll"
          >
            <template #empty> No callsfound. </template>
            <template #loading> Loading calls data. Please wait. </template>
            <Column
              selectionMode="multiple"
              headerStyle="width: 3rem"
            ></Column>
            <Column field="sqd" header="Sqd" sortable style="min-width: 14rem">
              <template #body="{ data }">
                {{ data.sqd }}
              </template>
              <template #filter="{ filterModel }">
                <PrimeInputText
                  type="text"
                  v-model="filterModel.value"
                  class="p-column-filter"
                  placeholder="Search by sqd"
                />
              </template>
            </Column>
            <Column
            
              field="call"
              header="Call "
              sortable
              filterMatchMode="contains"
              style="min-width: 14rem"
            >
              <template #body="{ data }">
            
                <span class="image-text">{{ data.call }}</span>
              </template>
              <template #filter="{ filterModel }">
                <InputText
                  type="text"
                  v-model="filterModel.value"
                  class="p-column-filter"
                  placeholder="Search by call"
                />
              </template>
            </Column>
    </Datatable>
```

> want to have doth filters and toggle column
> How can I make filters and toggle work together

Comment: i have implemented  another logic without using toggle select in the documentation